# Blocking bot by multi url pattern with fail2ban

Tags: fail2ban

I'm seeing a multi url pattern similar to following lines in nginx logs recently.

```
GET / 
GET /somepath/
GET /otherpath/
GET /
GET /somepath/
GET /otherpath/
...
```

I'm already using fail2ban for certain urls, but I could not find a solution for such pattern. Rules like "repetative requests more than n times per second for this url" are not fit for this behavior, for the bot makes 0-3 requests per second for the same url and such rule would also block multiple users sharing same ip number.

Is it possible to  apply a rule in fail2ban for multiple url pattern?

Comment: If i understand you correctly this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294957/block-visits-to-a-specific-url-with-fail2ban